# Error: Syntax error. Missing " on billing state in account object

Tags: formula, compile-error

I'm trying to assign a territory based on BillingState field in Salesforce and getting syntax error message Error: Syntax error. Missing "

```
    IF(ISBLANK(BillingState), "None",
    IF(CONTAINS("CA:WA:NV:OR:AK:HI”, BillingState), “Pacific”,
    IF(CONTAINS("AZ:CO:MT:NM:UT:WY:ID", BillingState), “Mountain”,
    IF(CONTAINS("AL:AR:IL:LA:MN:MS:MO:OK:WI:KS:NE:ND:SD:TX:TN", BillingState), “Central”,
    IF(CONTAINS("CT:DC:DE:GA:MN:MD:MA:NH:NJ:NY:NC:OH:PA:RI:SC:VT:VA:WV:FL:IN:MI", 
    BillingState), “East”,
    "Unknown"))))))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like in this line

```
"CA:WA:NV:OR:AK:HI”
```

The closing quote is not actually the right character. Replace it with this

```
"CA:WA:NV:OR:AK:HI"
```

Comment: Thank you you that solved it. For future reference this formula assigns a time zone to an account based on the billing state.